# how to rename image captured in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

In my application I need to capture image as well as save it on local library and on server using FTP. Now I need to follow a format for image name while saving it on the server. I am able to capture and save the image on local library. But I am unable to find any method to change the name of the Image. Suppose I need to rename it as **Productname-UserId.png** Is there any way? Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage*) is likely what you're looking for.  You can save a UIImage as a PNG file in the Application Documents folder, then upload that to a server.  The code to do this is quite trivial, so if you could post the code you're trying to use, that would be helpful to understanding, and recommending a solution for you.

Here's a short clipping from my code that does exactly this:

```
UIImage * image; // Some image you want to send

NSString * docDirWithSlash = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString * pngFile = [docDirWithSlash stringByAppendingString:file]; // <-- Change the string "file" to reflect the name you want.
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngFile atomically:YES];

// Send pngFile to the server here
```

Where applicationDocumentsDirectory looks like this:

```
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectoryPath;
}
```

Comment: You took my question in wrong way,I am able to upload the image file on server but I need to rename it with some format as stated in my question.

Comment: Isn't that a server issue then?  Or do you mean issue a "ren" command in FTP?

Comment: @Sarah , What name you are getting right now? When you are storing image are you giving name to a file, i.e. your IO logic when you are actually write file on disk just change name their!

Comment: I was able to change name using the above code. Thank you @CharlesChappell. Before I was getting name of the image library.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Don't forget to delete the generated files so they don't pile up.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is where do you want the file name to be specific? On the device or on the server. In case of device use Charles answer, otherwise you should look at http protocol(file upload part). Actually it doesn't matter what name the file have on you local device, as when you send it to the server over http, you can provide any name. The tricky part here is that the server you are uploading to should take that parameter into account when saving that file. So if you are uploading to a server that you don't have hand on and it does some self naming convention - you probably stuck. If it's yours - look at how you're saving files on the server side and if you are taking in account that "filename" parameter...
P.S. And don't forget to pass that argument to the upload request :)

Comment: Thank you ariel for the solution but i already implemented the above one.

Comment: Yea, I got it from comments :)